# In Ruby on Rails, how to intercept the Devise gem's email sending functionality and change it to call an API instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a working Rails installation with the Devise gem. Instead of sending emails for example for password recovery, I would like to make an API call. Is there a method or a file in Devise that I need to change to change the default email sending behaviour, and be able to send the same email content through an API instead?

Comment: Thanks! I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126052/devise-send-instructions-with-my-mail-wrapper but I don't understand where to put the code found in the comment. Wonder if you can help out?

Comment: In the model that you use for the devise users (i.e. `user` or `admin` or `customer`).